# textbox content refreshing

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, textbox

I'd like to set textbox content to the current date and time.
So, it's:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        date_TextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

but how to refresh it each second?
Help, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) to fire an event every second to update the textbox

```
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += (s,e) => date_TextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```